# Установка пакета matplotlib с помощью pip3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

Пишу в консоли:

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

И в результате ошибка:

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/0c/653aec68e9cfb775c4fbae8f71011206e5e7fe4d60fcf01ea1a9d3bc957f/matplotlib-3.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [3.0.2]
                    python: yes [3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06)  [GCC
                            5.4.0 20160609]]
                  platform: yes [linux]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.15.4]
          install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                            be found.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-izaasteb/matplotlib/
```

ОС: linux mint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением оказалось:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```